# Reputation graph -> Where exactly are the Year labels pointing to?

Tags: support, reputation-graph

The reputation graph (located in the upper-right section of a user's "Activity" profile) often nags me when I try to quickly comprehend it's content. The horizontal-axis labels seem to be not quite descriptive enough.

I *think* this is because there are no markers showing exactly where those points lie on the graph.

Perhaps the question could be narrowed down to a few options (see the "|" characters above the Year labels):

**a:**

```
                       _
8k                ____|
                _|
4k             |
              |
0 ___________|
------|----|----|----|--
    2014 2015 2016 2017
```

**b:**

```
                       _
8k                ____|
                _|
4k             |
              |
0 ___________|
----|----|----|----|----
    2014 2015 2016 2017
```

**c:**

```
                       _
8k                ____|
                _|
4k             |
              |
0 ___________|
-------|----|----|----|-
    2014 2015 2016 2017
```