# Reputation Graph Year Label Misleading

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

Hello and happy new year. Because it's the new year, I can clearly see what appears to be an issue with the axis labels and minor lines on the X axis of the SO reputation graph.

[image: reputation-graph-gi0rgi0s]

Looks like a lot of my 2019 activity has bled into 2020. This is my first meta post; I hope it's OK.

A similar issue was raised here: [Reputation graph -> Where exactly are the Year labels pointing to?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354661/reputation-graph-where-exactly-are-the-year-labels-pointing-to)

Comment: Reported multiple times before, they are not interested in fixing it.

Comment: … or maybe they don't know *how* to fix it?

Comment: The other similar questions I found were more like requests for clarity. They didn't clearly illustrate the problem like the picture above does.

Comment: @honk The answerer of the question that you referenced said this bug is different than the one that they answered. Please reopen this question

Comment: Freehand circle?!